# jQuery AJAX Request to HTTPS getting served to HTTP with Laravel and Select2

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, https, jquery-select2

I have a relatively simple Laravel app, that features an HTML form which contains a tag select element. The select element gets enhanced via select2 library. The tags are fetched via an XMLHttpRequest. I've [created a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjwxcxa2/6/), and the error I receive there is the same as on my production machine:

> [...]was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://blog.mazedlx.net/tags?term=asd'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
$('#tags_id').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [','],
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://blog.mazedlx.net/tags/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            var queryParameters = {
                term: params.term
            }
            return queryParameters;
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.tag,
                        id: item.id
                    };
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see in the fiddle the ajax url contains https, and the page containing the form is also served over https. The url also yields results: e.g. https://blog.mazedlx.net/tags?term=php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you check in the console you can see the request is going to the `http://` protocol, not `https://`, hence the error

Comment: as you can see in the code, the ajax call goes to a `https` resource

Comment: The code says it does, but the console is king: http://i.imgur.com/9jzpgyZ.png

Comment: so, where do i start debugging? even if the request comes via `http` my server is configured to redirect to `https`, always.

Comment: Hey @mazedlx, try using a secure middleware in laravel & let us know the results. See: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/secure-middleware-for-laravel-5

Comment: I'd rather let the web server handle insecure requests, but, ok. Created a middleware that will redirect to secure if the request is unsecure. I check for `$request->secure()` but it returns `false` although the page is served via `https`. I am not behind any proxy oder hoster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Needed to modify my Apache conf for that vhost. The SSL directives where only loaded for the main domain, but not for that subdomain.

Comment: what did you modify ?